# How can I send an auto connect feature packet in OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, shell-script

I am trying to configure auto connect feature on my router. It auto connects on a trigger packet. I need to provide the information of trigger packet. I need source port, destination port and protocol (TCP/UDP/ICMP)
Or I could just specify a protocol. I am not sure what am I supposed to enter, so, let's not consider this.

What would be the best way to solve the problem of this trigger?

I am on OS X.

Comment: Why not just `ping` the router?

Comment: What's the source port number and destination port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `ping` the router?

`ping` uses ICMP, which does not need TCP or UDP since they are higher layers in the Internet protocol suite.
Hence no port numbers, which are a TCP & UDP concept.  (When you ask about **ports**, you are actually referring to **TCP/UDP ports**.  An *Ethernet port* would probably refer to an RJ-45 jack.  An *IP port* seems to be an undefined entity.)

See [How does Ping Really Work?](http://www.galaxyvisions.com/pdf/white-papers/How_does_Ping_Work_Style_1_GV.pdf)

> There are three commonly encountered types of sockets: stream, datagram, and raw. TCP uses the stream type
>   and UDP uses the datagram type. Raw sockets are used by any application that needs to interact directly with
>   IP, bypassing TCP and UDP in doing so. Customers include routing protocol implementations like routed and
>   gated (that implement RIP and OSPF). It also includes our friend ping.

Answer (score 2):

[Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) can send a packet to any arbitrary TCP or UDP port.